# Identificar versão do Android por algum método

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Existe algum método para identificar a versão do Android do usuário assim que ele entrar no aplicativo?

Será útil para o aplicativo executar ou não animações entre transições de telas, caso o usuário tiver uma versão mais antiga, não executará, caso tiver uma versão mais atualizada, executara a transição animada.

Answer (score 5):

Sim, você pode verificar pelas constantes de versão.

Em geral, para tratamento de incompatibilidade de algumas funções da API é comum usar a constante [`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT), que possui a informação de qual versão o dispositivo esta rodando.

E junto com os valores dos SDK's, disponível na classe [`Build.VERSION_CODES`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) você consegue executar código condicionado a versão em que o aplicativo irá rodar.

Um exemplo seria:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    ViewPropertyAnimator vpa = view.animate();

    // Restante do código usando ViewPropertyAnimator

} else {
    Animation an = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f);

    // Restante do código usando a API View Animation
}
```

Esse código não irá funcionar para dispositivos com versão menor que o SDK 4 (Android 1.6 Donut), essas constantes foram adicionadas nessa versão.